# Determine the size of a SQL result set in KB

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle10g

I am hoping to find how I can get the kb size of a result set in OracleDB.
I am not an sysadmin, but often run queries that return over 100k rows and I would need to find a way to determine what is the total kb size.
thank you

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In SQL*Plus:

```
SET AUTOTRACE ON

SELECT *
FROM emp
WHERE rownum <= 100;

        27  recursive calls
         0  db block gets
        19  consistent gets
         4  physical reads
         0  redo size
     **11451  bytes sent via SQL*Net to client**
       314  bytes received via SQL*Net from client
         8  SQL*Net roundtrips to/from client
         0  sorts (memory)
         0  sorts (disk)
       100  rows processed
```

To use AUTOTRACE requires the PLUSTRACE role, which is not granted by default. [Find out more](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQPUG/ch_eight.htm#SQPUG535).

Comment: Wow, that's amazing. Autotrace actually *knew* that you were interested in bytes sent and marked the lines with asterisks? You'd think Oracle would at least fix the bug that caused the misalignment of numbers though. :-) +1 for a better answer than mine.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, indeed the autotrace is great. 
Still have one more issue - I use SQL Developer and it seems that there are some unreturned results (the ones that I need :().
When I set autotrace ON and run the SELECT, I get the following results:
  Statistics
685  recursive calls
3  db block gets
22744  consistent gets
247  physical reads
0  redo size
0  workarea executions - multipass
0  parse time cpu
0  parse time elapsed
0  frame signature mismatch
2  execute count

Any tips and tricks on how this can be further tuned to retrieve the required results?

Comment: Note that "bytes sent via SQL*Net to client" represents the total amount of traffic from the server to the client, which includes more than just the result set itself. e.g. SELECT null FROM DUAL; => 411 bytes sent via SQL*Net to client (tested on Oracle 11.1)

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you would replace your column list with a `count(*)` to return the row count.

I'm not sure how well that would work on really complicated queries with many joins and such but, for simpler queries, it should be fine. Replace:

```
select a,b,c from t where a > 7;
```

with

```
select count(*) from t where a > 7;
```

That will give you the row count before you run the real query. Just keep in mind there's a chance the data may change between your count query and real query (hopefully not too much). Knowledge of the data properties will allow you to approximate kilobytes from row count.